# React with Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to start a react app, and use firebase for my database. Im using the .on() method in the componentDidMount() and everything works except for the .on() method. Ive tried debugger and console logging but nothing shows up.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('object')
  rootRef.on('value', function(snap) {
    console.log('hello')
  })
}
```

Comment: So what is the question? React with Firebase is pretty broad and you haven't stated a specific technical issue here. Also, you should begin by adding a cancel callback (which would alert you of the error) and turning on debug logging if you're still confused: `firebase.database().enableLogging(true);`

Comment: One possible cause is that you don't have read permission to the data. See [detecting errors when reading data in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/23610/detecting-errors-when-reading-data-in-javascript#t=201609232249519812555)